# Update database with new data (products, categories etc)

Tags: magento-1.9, database-update

We have a live magento site with version 1.7.

In a dev installation (magento 1.9) , we had put a snap of live site database.

In dev site, we have changed theme, we have added some extension and we have done some other changes.

While we worked at dev site, in live site we have added products, we have had sales, more customers added etc.

How we can update dev database (with new products, new customers, new sales from live site database) without losing other changes we have made in dev site?

Comment: Ideally, your changes would be made in upgrade or installer scripts so you can refresh the dev DB from live and re run all your updated configuration. It will also be important for when you decide to go live with the update

Answer (score 3):

You can do the following:

Dump your CMS and Static Block data along with your config to a sql file.
You can then re-run the upgrade from your current live (1.7 to 1.9 upgrade)
You can then re-import your new data from your dev site back to you dev site.

The procedure will be something like this:

```
mysqldump -uuser -p'password' livedatabase cms_page cms_page_store cms_block cms_block_store core_config_data > temp-data-backup.sql
```

Then backup and restore your current live site to your dev site (All your customers and orders will be on your dev)

Now you can restore the data from cms and config by doing the following

```
mysql -uuser -p'password' devdatabase < temp-data-backup.sql
```

Before you start the above make a backup of your current dev database in case you have to go back.

You will have all your customers, orders, product and categories from live along with all your changed config data, cms and static block from dev.